# How do I get the list of fieldname/elements from a JAXB generated java file?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to figure out how to get the list of elements (all the names in the 'propOrder') from an auto-generated Java file that was created using JAXB. I want something along the lines of:

**List String> elements = getXMLElements(ExampleInfo.class);**

I can't edit the generated java class because the XSD schema might be changed. I'm trying to get the elements which would be startTime, stopTime, and id.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "exampleInfo", propOrder = {
    "startTime",
    "stopTime",
    "id",
     ...
})

public class ExampleInfo
    extends TypeInfo
{

    @XmlElement(name = "StartTime")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar startTime;
    @XmlElement(name = "StopTime")
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar stopTime;
    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    ...
}
```

Comment: You can fetch fields from any class using java reflection mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it quite easily with the help of method  [`Class.getAnnotation(Class<A>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getAnnotation-java.lang.Class-):

```
public static List<String> getXMLElements(Class<?> clazz) {
    XmlType xmlType = clazz.getAnnotation(XmlType.class);
    if (xmlType == null)
        return null;
    String[] propOrder = xmlType.propOrder();
    return Arrays.asList(propOrder);
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
List<String> elements = getXMLElements(ExampleInfo.class);
```